# need max(id)for multiple rows but am receiving multiple max id's

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to retrieve the latest loadid by location now with multiple joins.
for example ibiza's latest loadid is 692 and there are 2 records. The query below retrieves all of the loadid's for that location and not just the max. how can i achieve bringing back the latest records by location with the max(loadid) from the query below:

```
select
MAX(t.loadid) AS loadid,
a.process_id,
p.partitionkey,
-- t.partitionkey,
p.partdesc,
p.partname,
c.catname,
r.rule_name,
r.file_path,
a.execution_start_time,
a.execution_end_time,
a.records_processed
--  a.status,
--  a.last_updated_by as processed_by,
--  a.last_update_date
FROM
data t
INNER JOIN part p
ON t.partitionkey = p.partitionkey
INNER JOIN process a
ON t.loadid = a.process_id
INNER JOIN categ c
ON t.catkey = c.catkey
INNER JOIN balance r
ON t.RULE_ID = r.RULE_ID
WHERE
p.partname = 'ibiza'
GROUP BY
t.loadid,
a.process_id,
p.partitionkey,
t.partitionkey,
p.partdesc,
p.partname,
c.catname,
r.rule_name,
r.file_path,
a.execution_start_time,
a.execution_end_time,
a.records_processed;
```

Comment: You have t.loadid in your group by. Remove that from the group by so you can get the max value of that for the other columns as a group.

Comment: create some sample test data and expected output

Answer (score -1):

You can use CTE :

```
;WITH MaxLoadId AS
(
    select MAX(t.loadid) AS loadid, p.partitionkey, p.partdesc, p.partname
    FROM data t
        INNER JOIN part p ON t.partitionkey = p.partitionkey
    WHERE p.partname = 'ibiza'
    GROUP BY p.partitionkey, p.partdesc, p.partname
)
select
    mli.loadid AS loadid,
    a.process_id,
    mli.partitionkey,
    -- t.partitionkey,
    mli.partdesc,
    mli.partname,
    c.catname,
    r.rule_name,
    r.file_path,
    a.execution_start_time,
    a.execution_end_time,
    a.records_processed
    --  a.status,
    --  a.last_updated_by as processed_by,
    --  a.last_update_date
FROM MaxLoadId mli
    INNER JOIN data t ON mli.loadid = t.loadid
    INNER JOIN process a ON mli.loadid = a.process_id
    INNER JOIN categ c ON t.catkey = c.catkey
    INNER JOIN balance r ON t.RULE_ID = r.RULE_ID
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but the query returns 0 records

Comment: Yes, there is a mistake in the query.

Comment: Thanks for the update, i tried a few things but am now receiving he multi-part identifier "t.catkey" could not be bound.

Comment: Thanks, almost there, I now have the 2 returned rows repeating 40 times (80 rows)

Comment: Can you add details about the relations between the tables ?